# Algorithm with O(n) to find min and max of triple product in subsets

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

The problem is to find the min and max triple product (product of 3 numbers) that can be formed, given an array of numbers. I managed to work out a code which works perfect, but it has got complexity `(N^2)`. I need some help in reducing it to `O(N)` if possible.

Edit: Numbers can be both positive and negative.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Result {

    public static int min =50000000;
    public static int max =-50000000;

    public static int solve(int pos, int currPro, int depth) {
            if (depth==3){
                check(currPro);
            }
            else {
                for (int i=1; i<=Triplet.data.length-pos; i++){
                if(pos+i < Triplet.data.length){
                    solve(pos+i,currPro*Triplet.data[pos+i],depth+1); 
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void check(int currPro) {
        if (currPro > max){
            max = currPro;
        }

        if (currPro < min){
            min = currPro;
        }
    }
}

class Triplet {

    static int[] data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt(); //Number of int
        data = new int[num];
        for (int i=0;i<num;i++){
            data[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        if (num==3){
            int result= data[0]*data[1]*data[2];
            System.out.println(""+result+" "+result);
        }
        else{
            Result.solve(-1, 1, 0);
            System.out.println(""+Result.min+" "+Result.max);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can any of the numbers be negative?  If they're all positive, it would seem like you can get the largest product just by finding the largest three numbers.  If they can be negative, you should still be able to adjust--find the largest three, find the smallest three, then if two of the smallest three are negative you'll have to try some cases multiplying two negatives and a positive...

Comment: You will not be able to achieve linear time. Linear time means going through the array once to find your values. I do not find that possible in this case unless it be by coincidence.

Comment: @TylerWeaver: No, it's pretty straightforward to do this in linear time.

Comment: @tmyklebu I must be missing something then. I said it because I personally cannot think of a way to travel the array once and find both answers. Normally there are many values to compare. Unless he sorts the array. But if the array is sorted, the algorithm may be linear time, but overall it won't be since every sorting algortihm cannot possibly be linear time. Also for max triples you may need to traverse the array at least two times so that already guarentees non-linear time

Comment: @TylerWeaver: It's a selection problem, not sorting.  Find the three most positive numbers, the three most negative numbers, the three smallest positive numbers, and the three smallest negative numbers.  That step takes linear time.  Then try all possibilities.

Comment: @tmyklebu Ahhh I see what you're getting at now. I never thought about selecting all possible values and trying the possibilities. This would cause the non-linear growth to be put into arrays of size 6 which is much more manageable. Or just multiply all of the possibilities. That's creative I must say

Answer (score 4):

Try this

1. Find three smallest and three largest numbers (regardless negative or positive ones) with quick sort partition in O(N) time.
2. Apply your O(N^2) solution to array of 6 numbers.

Running time - O(N)